# Can the default Android Browser using Javascript retrieve data from a custom Android app using Content Provider?

Tags: javascript, android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create a custom Android app using Content Provider to forward data from the app to the default Android web browser by using JavaScript within the HTML code of a particular site that I will create. Is it possible for the Content Provider and the JavaScript to share data with one another?

If so, how can this be done? 
If this is not possible through Content Providers, is there another way to query data using JavaScript on the Android web browser from the custom android app?

Thanks